# Can modal verb+have+pp express continuity?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-participles

> “Well, and you have told me what to do! Let us buy them opium to
>   enjoy, and more opium, and let them have their will of it as rich
>   people do. I will seem to be friends with my cousin again and I will
>   entice him away to the tea house in the town where one can smoke and
>   we can buy it for my uncle and his wife.”
>  But Wang Lung, since he
>   had not thought of the thing first himself, was doubtful.
>  “It
>   will cost a great deal,” he said slowly, “for opium is as dear as
>   jade.”
>  “Well, and it is dearer than jade to have them at us like
>   this,” the young man argued, “and to endure besides their haughtiness
>   and the young man peeping at my wife.”
>  But Wang Lung would not at
>   once consent, for it was not so easy a thing to do, and it would cost
>   a good bag of silver to do it.
>  It is doubtful whether the thing
>   (1) **would ever have been done** and they (2) **would have gone** as
>   they were until the waters chose to recede had not a thing
>   happened.
>  This thing was that the son of Wang Lung’s uncle cast
>   his eyes upon the second daughter of Wang Lung, who was his cousin and
>   by blood the same as his sister.   
>   (The Good Earth, Pearl S. Buck,
>   p299)

(2), unlike (1), has the meaning of ‘continuity.’ Can we use the ‘modal verb+have+pp’ to express continuity, even without the time-clause and subjunctive mood?

*continuity: "from a point in the past to either the present or the near present"
(Understanding English Grammar.Kolln, p79)

Comment: This is Too Localised. It's *bad English*, because the initial *It is doubtful* isn't actually what's supposed to modify *(2) would have gone...* What the author *intends* as a modifier to that second possibility is *it is **probable***, not *doubtful*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ; You need to read StoneyB’s the world’s best explanation about this issue.[link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3793/why-is-it-awkward-when-i-re-write-this/3799#3799) Then you can seen Buck’s English can’t be blamed from you.

Comment: I don't see the connection with that link. But now you call my attention to it, this whole passage is in a rather curious prose style. *It is doubtful whether the thing* will help you learn modern English usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Tense is a BIG ISSUE in English grammar books, isn’t it? Then what are your grounds that this is ‘Too localized’? YOU SHOULD explain the reason!

Comment: @FumbleFingers is right on both counts. A) There should be a comma or a semicolon after *done*. B) This **is** a very odd style. Pearl Buck was bilingual and her greatest influences were  the King James Bible and the classic Chinese novel.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, IN MY Country, even elementary school students learn their ancient stories, and secondary students learn VERY OLD Korean literatures – even longer than a thousand years - to learn OUR language. DO you not learn OLD English in your elementary and secondary school? : Yeah, I know what you are to say. But your modern English don’t give me much interesting and learning experience more than your classics. I learn more from your classics. I even tried Shakespeare. What’s the matter?

Comment: As for your question: the 'continuity' is a function of the verb *go*, rather than the tense. This would be clearer if Buck had used the more modern idiom *go on* instead of the 16th century sense of *go* as *proceed*.

Comment: Don't scold FumbleFingers; it's not his fault. No, our children are not taught old literature - there are people all over this site complaining that *Jane Eyre*! is archaic. Instruction in the English language has passed out of the hands of those who know and love both the language and the literature into the hands of those who believe that the language is merely a tool (and not a very good one) and the literature a distraction from learning how to write business plans.

Comment: @StoneyB: OP's interspliced brackets tend to blur the syntax even more, but I'm not convinced the "sentence" is properly salvaged by just adding a comma. Replacing the word "and" with a period would make more sense to me. Two "would have" clauses in the same sentence would naturally be expected to be *both* governed by the same leading clause, comma or no.